# Azure DevOps VSTS .netcore build failing, but works fine on my PC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I keep getting dependencies errors in my .net core2.1.1 MVC website. It builds fine from my PC. but Azure DevOps is not compiling refrences properly.

**Adding a couple of pics to help sort this out.**
[image]
[image]

**DevOps Error. After I added a update nuget to the latest**

The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(NU1607: Version conflict detected for Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions. Reference the package directly from the project to resolve this issue. 
 CBW.Website (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design (>= 2.1.5) -> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc (>= 2.1.5) -> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration (>= 2.1.5) -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection (>= 2.1.1) -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions (>= 2.1.1) 
 CBW.Website (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App (>= 2.1.0) -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions (>= 2.1.0).
Errors in D:\a\1\s\CBW.Website\CBW.Website.csproj
    NU1607: Version conflict detected for Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions. Reference the package directly from the project to resolve this issue.
     CBW.Website (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design (>= 2.1.5) -> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc (>= 2.1.5) -> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration (>= 2.1.5) -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection (>= 2.1.1) -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions (>= 2.1.1)
     CBW.Website (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App (>= 2.1.0) -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions (>= 2.1.0).)

Packages failed to restore

***************Edit
I passed the nuget errors based on and targeting the everything to version 2.1.5 in my csproj. Now I am back to the restore error.
[image]

**My Csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
     <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.1.5</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-AspNetCorePagesIdentity-***************-***-*******-</UserSecretsId>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>3.0</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>True</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Client\assets\controlbyweb-logo.png" />
    <Content Include="Client\assets\webrelay_170.png" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.5" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Areas\Identity\Services\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="Client\_ViewImports.cshtml">
      <Pack>$(IncludeRazorContentInPack)</Pack>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>


</Project>
```

**** error**

```
2018-10-08T14:44:09.2159846Z   Restoring packages for D:\a\1\s\CBW.Website\CBW.Website.csproj...
2018-10-08T14:44:09.7085782Z C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dncs\1.0.4\x64\sdk\1.0.4\NuGet.targets(97,5): error : Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design 2.1.5 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design 2.1.5 supports: [D:\a\1\s\CBW.Website\CBW.Website.csproj]
2018-10-08T14:44:09.7094563Z C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dncs\1.0.4\x64\sdk\1.0.4\NuGet.targets(97,5): error :   - net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1) [D:\a\1\s\CBW.Website\CBW.Website.csproj]
2018-10-08T14:44:09.7099570Z C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dncs\1.0.4\x64\sdk\1.0.4\NuGet.targets(97,5): error :   - netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0) [D:\a\1\s\CBW.Website\CBW.Website.csproj]
2018-10-08T14:44:09.7102618Z C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dncs\1.0.4\x64\sdk\1.0.4\NuGet.targets(97,5): error : Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.6 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.6 supports: [D:\a\1\s\CBW.Website\CBW.Website.csproj]
2018-10-08T14:44:09.7103331Z C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dncs\1.0.4\x64\sdk\1.0.4\NuGet.targets(97,5): error :   - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5) [D:\a\1\s\CBW.Website\CBW.Website.csproj]
2018-10-08T14:44:09.7103534Z C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dncs\1.0.4\x64\sdk\1.0.4\NuGet.targets(97,5): error :   - netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0) [D:\a\1\s\CBW.Website\CBW.Website.csproj]
2018-10-08T14:44:09.7103694Z        Package Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders 2.1.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders 2.1.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
2018-10-08T14:44:10.0475303Z       Package Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers 2.1.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers 2.1.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
2018-10-08T14:44:10.0475426Z       Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc 2.1.5 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc 2.1.5 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
2018-10-08T14:44:10.0475562Z       One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1.
2018-10-08T14:44:10.0475666Z   
2018-10-08T14:44:10.0475771Z   NuGet Config files used:
2018-10-08T14:44:10.0475909Z       D:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_13.config
2018-10-08T14:44:10.0476013Z   
2018-10-08T14:44:10.0476113Z   Feeds used:
2018-10-08T14:44:10.0476241Z       https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
2018-10-08T14:44:10.1010270Z ##[error]Error: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dncs\1.0.4\x64\dotnet.exe failed with return code: 1
2018-10-08T14:44:10.1032411Z ##[error]Packages failed to restore
2018-10-08T14:44:10.1055895Z ##[section]Finishing: Restore
```

Comment: Did you build release on your machine?

Comment: Try upgrading `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` to **2.1.5**

Comment: why not just use dotnet publish to implicitly restore packages, why use nuget direclty as a stage?

Comment: I added the Nuget based on a GitHub bug I found about dependencies.

Comment: I built release on my machine to make sure. It works fine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved it
Edit 7/5/19
The YML file or the editor has the same issue with the .netcore SDK version. I have updated mine multiple times now. It will break randomly when the core SDK team pushes updates to Nuget, or you update VS or sometimes.. My builds are automated and it works today and tomorrow it does not, after 0 code changes.  But I always come back to this fix and then it builds again.

Get your SDK version in VS2017
[image]

Set your version in DevOps
[image]

Comment: This and higher NuGet version, e.g. ASP.NET Core 2.2.105 + Nuget 4.9.4 works

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest checking the following 2 items:

1. Build in RELEASE locally and see if the problem is reproduced.
2. Be specific about NuGet version in VSTS:
   [image]

   [image]

Comment: I built in release mode before posting and this is exactly how I am calling nuget. except I'm calling 4.3.0, I am trying 4.4.1 now.... And it didn't help

Answer (score 1):

For those of you configuring through a YAML file: I was dealing with these issues too but it was because I simply copied a deployment YAML file from somewhere else and did not use the proper tooling. After following this tutorial, it worked like a charm:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops

More specifically, I think using the dotnet restore to restore your packages might fix it:

```
steps:
- script: dotnet restore
```

Make sure to install the correct .NET Core SDK, too.

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
  inputs:
    version: '2.1.300' # replace this value with the version that you need for your project
```