# Azure DevOps restore fails

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget, azure-devops

I added a nuget restore which works fine.  Dev and Release build works fine on my pc.
Its failing in Azure Devops restore.

Link to error txt
[Error.txt](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/storage/attachments/43485-error.txt)

**My Csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">    
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
     <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.1.5</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-AspNetCorePagesIdentity-***************-***-*******-</UserSecretsId>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>3.0</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>True</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Client\assets\control-logo.png" />
    <Content Include="Client\assets\webrelay_170.png" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.5" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Areas\Identity\Services\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="Client\_ViewImports.cshtml">
      <Pack>$(IncludeRazorContentInPack)</Pack>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Are you using a hosted agent or a private agent?

Comment: I think you are using `.Net core 2.1` ? I such case i doubt that hosted agent Vs2017 will not work with `.Net core2.1`

Comment: I got it to work and Yes I am using the VS2017 Hosted

Comment: I solved it and posted here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52694196/azure-devops-vsts-netcore-build-failing-but-works-fine-on-my-pc/52772297#52772297

Answer (score 0):

You need to use cmd line and use "dotnet restore" not build in nuget restore task.

in yaml

`steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    feedsToUse: config
    nugetConfigPath: NuGet.config    # Relative to root of the repository
    externalFeedCredentials: <Name of the NuGet service connection>`