# Azure DevOps Server dotnet restore has no access to feed

Tags: azure-devops

I need to use the `.NET Core` build pipeline task with the `restore` command. Target is to restore the package references (`*.nupkg`) of a solution. I have two package sources:

- nuget.org
- private artifacts feed (*MyFeed*) on ADS

Some projects in my solution refer the packages from *MyFeed* and needs to restored on agent before build.

[image]

---

### The Error

The task fail when it try to download the packages from my private feed *MyFeed*: (unfortunately the output is on german so i put the error message into google translator and hope the best)

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.402\NuGet.targets(128,5): error: Error getting information about "ext.lib.MyPackage" from the remote source "https://MyUrl.de/Collection/_packaging/38df75fe-122d-57f9-af47-de3a09231f5e/nuget/v3/flat2/ext.lib .MyPackage / index.json ".
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.402\NuGet.targets (128,5): error: No login information is available in the security package. [D:\AzureDevOpsData\Agents\MyAgent\_work\2\s\MySolution.sln]
```

---

### What I have done?

Use NuGet Task

I try to reproduce that behavior with the `NuGet` task, but with this task everything works fine. This task has access to my private feed *MyFeed*. *Important: the `NuGet` task is no alternative for use, we need to use the `.NET Core` task*

Windows Credential Manager

I add my feed to the Package Manager in Visual Studio 2019 on my agent and enter the credentials of my agent user. In result of the an 2 entries added to my Windows Credential Manager.

[image]

This change do not solve the issue, the error message is the same.

---

### Edit 1: add Auth to NuGet.Config

I try to add the Auth to my `NuGet.Config`. This approach has many variables, I try to list all varieties I try.

#### NuGet.Config Path

The `dotnet restore` task provides to options for a NuGet config:

[image]

1. Option: I associate with the `%APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config` (but I am not sure)
2. Option: is a `NuGet.Config` path to your repository

**So for all runs I try always BOTH options!**

1. Run: `Username` with `Domain Password` (Encrypted) ❌
2. Run: `Username` with `PAT` (ClearTextPassword) ❌
3. Run: `Domain\Username` with `PAT` (ClearTextPassword) ❌
4. Run: `Username` with `Domain Passwort` (ClearTextPassword) ❌
5. Run: `Domain\Username` with `Domain Passwort` (ClearTextPassword) ❌

#### NuGet.Config structure for all runs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="MyFeed" value="https://MyFeedUrl/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <config>
    <add key="http_proxy" value="http://www-MyProxy.de:3000" />
    <add key="https_proxy" value="http://www-MyProxy.de:3000" />
  </config>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <MyFeed>
        <add key="Username" value="$MyRunUser" />
        <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="$MyRunKey" /> <- ClearTextPassword OR Password
        <add key="ValidAuthenticationTypes" value="basic" />
      </MyFeed>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

#### Temporary NuGet.Config

Doesn't matter what I do, the `dotnet` task always create and use a temporary `NuGet.Config`. From the `system.deubg = true` log I could get:

```
##[debug]Getting credentials for local feeds
SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
##[debug]SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
##[debug]Got auth token
##[debug]externalEndpoints=null
##[debug]Setting up sources
##[debug]selectOrConfig=config
##[debug]nugetConfigPath=D:\AzureDevOpsData\Agents\MyAgent\_work\18\s\MyNuGet.Config
##[debug]check path : D:\AzureDevOpsData\Agents\MyAgent\_work\18\s\MyNuGet.Config
##[debug]nugetConfigPath=D:\AzureDevOpsData\Agents\MyAgent\_work\18\s\MyNuGet.Config
##[debug]Absolute path for pathSegments: D:\AzureDevOpsData\Agents\MyAgent\_work\18\s\MyNuGet.Config = D:\AzureDevOpsData\Agents\MyAgent\_work\18\s\MyNuGet.Config
##[debug]build.sourcesDirectory=D:\AzureDevOpsData\Agents\MyAgent\_work\18\s
##[debug]Absolute path for pathSegments: D:\AzureDevOpsData\Agents\MyAgent\_work\18\s = D:\AzureDevOpsData\Agents\MyAgent\_work\18\s
##[debug]nugetConfigPathpath supplied :true
##[debug]Agent.BuildDirectory=D:\AzureDevOpsData\Agents\MyAgent\_work\18
##[debug]build.buildId=15914
##[debug]Setting auth in the temp nuget.config
"NuGet.config" wird in einer temporären Konfigurationsdatei gespeichert.
##[debug]Getting sources from NuGet.config in this location: D:\AzureDevOpsData\Agents\MyAgent\_work\18\Nuget\tempNuGet_12914.config
```

**Temporary NuGet.Config:**

```
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3"/>
    
  <add key="feed-MyFeed" value="https://MyAdsUrl.de/MyCollection/_packaging/MyFeed/nuget/v3/index.json"/></packageSources>
  <config>
    <add key="http_proxy" value="http://www-cache.MyProxy.de:3000"/>
    <add key="https_proxy" value="http://www-cache.MyProxy.de:3000"/>
  </config>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    
  <feed-MyFeed><add key="Username" value="VssSessionToken"/><add key="ClearTextPassword" value="QhbGcsadsasadd... VERY LONG KEY-PA"/></feed-MyFeed></packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

From my perspective I can see the temprary `Nuget.Config` contains my custom **proxy** and my custom **feed**, but **not** my custom authentication.

**Does that mean that the `dotnet` task do not use my custom `NuGet.Config`?**

---

#### Meta Information

- ADS and Agent is self-hosted
- Version: 17.153.29207.5 (AzureDevOps2019.Update1)
- Proxy: Yes

Answer (score 2):

You can try putting the credentials of your azure artifacts feed in your nuget.config file.

First you need to generate a [Personal access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) from Azure devops with the **Read&Write Packaging** scope.

Then you can provide the credentials to the azure feed for your nuget source. See below example:

```
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="AzureArtifactFeedName" value="http://dctfs2019:8080/tfs/Collection/_packaging/AzureArtifactFeedName/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <AzureArtifactFeedName>
        <add key="Username" value="any" />
        <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="{Personal Access Token}" />
      </AzureArtifactFeedName>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

You can also run below commands to add the feed credential:

```
sources Add -Name "AzureArtifactFeedName" -Source "http://dctfs2019:8080/tfs/Collection/_packaging/AzureArtifactFeedName/nuget/v3/index.json" -username any -password PersonalAccessToken -ConfigFile path/to/Nuget.config -StorePasswordInClearText
```

Then the package can be automatically pushed.

Also, you can try to add `<add key="ValidAuthenticationTypes" value="basic"/>` to the package source credentials to prevent nuget/dotnet from trying to authenticate via NTLM/Windows authentication.

Comment: Hey Alina, thanks a lot for your answer. I add a new section to my question *Edit 1: add Auth to NuGet.Config*. I would be so happy if you could read it. Unfortunately this approach do not work for me. But I have the adoption that the `dotnet` restore task ignores my custom auth configuration from my `NuGet.Config`. Can you confirm?

Comment: The `dotnet` task will also use the `VssSessionToken` in the temporary `nuget.config`, when I use a **nuget service connection**. There is no way to prevent the `dotnet` task creating temporary `nuget.config` files and there is no way to but custom authentication in that temporary config.

Answer (score 0):

In your pipelines try to add a Nuget Authenticate step first.
And make sure you have the persistcredentials set to true (checkout arguments)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The `NuGet Authenticate` task is not part of **Azure DevOps Server 2019**. See [NuGet Authenticate Not Found](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/950388/nuget-authenticate-not-found.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure DevOps Server dotnet restore has no access to feed

To resolve this issue, you could use the `nuget restore` task to restore the packages, and use the `dotnet build` task with argument `--no-restore`:

[image]

If you still want use `dotnet restore` instead of `nuget restore`, you could execute following `dotnet` command line in the Azure devops server machine:

```
dotnet nuget add source http://xxxxx/DefaultCollection/_packaging/LeoTestFeed/nuget/v3/index.json -n YourFeedName -u YourUserName -p YourPAT --store-password-in-clear-text
```

You could check the document [dotnet nuget add source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-nuget-add-source) for some more details.

Then we could use the dotnet restore successful:

[image]

My test result(TFS 2018, Since my TFS2019 server is down for unknown reasons):

[image]

Comment: Ola Leo, thanks for your response. The `nuget restore` works for us in general too. But we overserve a strange behavior why we **can't** use it. In project file we use the package reference like `<PackageReference Include="ext.lib.MyPackage" Version="*" />` to always get the newest version of our packages from the feed. I have a package with version `4.0.0` in the feed. I had to make a very small change, so add a version counter to `4.0.0.1`. `nuget restore` task resolve this package randomly as `4.0.0` and some times as `4.0.0.1` (**local cache disabled**), so we lost the trust in that task.

Comment: Another requirement is to use the *full* `dotnet` tool chain for our builds. In principal we like the all in one `dotnet` approach. Unfortunately small issues (authentication) prevent the usage of `dotnet` in our pipelines.

Comment: Shouldn't I use the `dotnet nuget add source http://xxxxx/DefaultCollection/_packaging/LeoTestFeed/nuget/v3/index.json -n YourFeedName -u YourUserName -p YourPAT --store-password-in-clear-text` on my agents instead of me Azure DevOps Server Machine?

Comment: @MarTin, If your agent and Azure DevOps Server Machine are not in the same machine, use it in the agent machine.

Comment: I try the command on my agent, and the result is the same: `error: No login information is available in the security package`. I use a full access PAT, generated for my personal account. By the way, the workaround we use currently is a simple powershell inline script the executes: `dotnet restore $(Solution) --configfile $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\DotNet.Config`. The `DotNet.Config` is a custom config only with feed source information without auth.

Comment: @MarTin, The error message seems not related to the certification, you could check this document for some more details: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/10399 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53430896/nuget-restore-fails-on-azure-devops-with-message-unable-to-load-the-service-ind. BTW, Thank you for sharing your workaround, you could convert it as an answer before you get the better answer.